# Can't set brightness of screen Acer Aspire S3

Tags: brightness

I'm on the latest Linux Mint release on an Acer Aspire S3. Unfortunately I can't set the screen brightness in the Screen preferences. It doesn't matter which position the slider has, it's always the same brightness. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to set the brightness?

Comment: this still happens with Linux Mint 13 (Maya)

Comment: Still happening with Mint 16.  :(

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @RoQ is working fine. Here are the steps :

- Edit the  /etc/default/grub file with superuser privilege
- Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux"`
- Update the grub with the following command : `sudo update-grub` and reboot your computer

That's it

Answer (score 2):

Changing the grub command line is the right way to do it, but the problem is that `acpi_backlight=vendor` is wrong. The correct one is: `acpi_osi=Linux`

It still always worked for me on a lot of laptops.

Comment: This answer should get more attention. With `acpi_backlight=vendor` I got full brightness on my screen (so not as dark as it was without it), but no control over brightness. The `acpi_osi=Linux` argument did it both.

Comment: This answer worked for me with an ASUS K501UX with same results as @ShlomiNoach.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at fixing this in my LMDE 13 and came across this [How do I set default brightness after boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30924/how-do-i-set-default-brightness-after-boot).

It has fixed it for many, however in my case, I am not able to find a directory in `/sys/class/backlight`. Perhaps that means a proper driver is not loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would be a workaround, but I actually also need to be able to adjust the brightness using the FN key and not just telling it how bright the screen should be. When I'm on battery I don't want it to be max brightness, on AC I do.

Answer (score 1):

For mint mate 17, you can set the default brightness by following steps:

- sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
- Applications -> System Tools -> dconf tools,
- search for backlight, find and change following options:

  - `brightness-ac`: brightness when use AC powser (charged),
  - `brightness-dim-battery`: brightness when use battery (not charged),

Answer (score 1):

For all of you running a Laptop with NVIDIA Card and who are still not able to get the f* function keys for brightness to work, just follow the steps below. It worked very well for my system (Samsung q45, Intel Dualcore T7100 @ 1,8Ghz , Nvidia Geforce 8400M G 512) running Linux Mint 17.

In command line, type in:

sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

You will have to enter your root password.

Now, you should see:

---

Section "Device"
    Identifier            "Device0"
    Driver                "nvidia"
    VendorName      "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

---

If you see nothing, just enter all the lines above and follow up with the next step below

Under the VendorName Line, add the following:

---

Option    "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"

---

Now, save and reboot. Check your brightness controls, and hopefully this fixed things.

I've tried so many solutions out of the net and nothing had helped me until I came to this solution. But be aware that these steps only working for NVIDIA Grafics and you must have chosen the NVIDIA Driver in your system in "Administration -> Driver Manager".

Answer (score -1):

I added `acpi_osi=` to grub and this helped my Acer 5742z with intel graphics.